# How to prove this using Fermat's Little Theorem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes and $a$ is an integer such that $\text{gcd}(a,pq)=1$. 
Prove that $a^{(p-1)(q-1)+1}\equiv a \pmod{pq}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Can you use the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: We are not taught that theorem yet, so I'd really appreciate if there is any other way to prove this. Thank you!

Comment: See my comment to my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Use Fermat's Little Theorem to say $a^{p-1}\equiv1 \mod p$ and $a^{q-1}\equiv 1 \mod q.$

Therefore $a^{(p-1)(q-1)}\equiv 1 \mod p,q.$

Therefore $a^{(p-1)(q-1)}\equiv 1 \mod pq,$ using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Now multiply both sides by $a$.

Comment: If you don’t want to invoke CRT, will you accept primes $p,q|x-1\implies pq|x-1$ ?

Comment: Okay, but then I cannot figure out how I can apply this rule to prove it...

Comment: which rule?  Fermat's little theorem?  that was used to prove $a^{p-1}\equiv1\mod p$ and same for $q$; then $x=a^{(p-1)(q-1)}\equiv1 \mod p,q$; the next line in my answer uses either CRT or the alternative in my comment

Comment: Ah okay, that was very helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(p-1)(q-1)$ is the value of Euler's phi-function; then go from there.